# How to delete a column using CSVed?

Tags: windows, csv, csved

I need to delete a column using CSVed, actually `Column 2` in this screenshot:
[image]
I tried right clicking on `Column 2` -> `Delete selected columns`
[image]
However this does not work, it gives me "Select one or more columns to delete":
[image]

Well, how can I select a column? I just couldn't figure out how to do that. Thanks!

The CSV file:

```
MyFirstcolumn,MySecondColumn,MyThird Column
one,two,three
another one,another two,another three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting the column you want to delete from the TAB section, then click on Delete Column.

[image]

Comment: wow, after testing it I can confirm this works. Still don't find it intuitive at all. Thanks for your support!